# Jquery autonumeric (gem 'autonumeric-rails') not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Jquery autonumeric is not loading correctly on page load.  If I refresh the page the jquery works, but provides 0.00, not the specified, 0 as specified here:  `$('input.number').number( true, 0 );`

Two issues I need to solve:

1) why it is not loading on the original page load

2) why `$('input.number').number( true, 0 );` is not working in setting the parameters.

## GemFile

```
gem 'autonumeric-rails'
```

## application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autonumeric
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require dynamic_select

$('input.number').number( true, 0 );
```

I also tried this:

## application.js (second version)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autonumeric
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require dynamic_select

$(document).ready(function() { 
            $('input.number').number( true, 0 );
            $(document).trigger('refresh_autonumeric');
    });
```

## _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field( :income,{value: 50000, :placeholder => "Income", class: "number form-control input-lg", data: {autonumeric: true} } ) %>
```

## update:

Removing `$('input.number').number( true, 0 );` seemed to get the below working.  However #2 is still an issue.  I can't get `.number(true, 0)` working

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
      $(document).trigger('refresh_autonumeric');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note : `number` is not an autoNumeric function.

Very recently autonumeric-rails has been updated (cf. this [PR](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/pull/337)), please try again with the latest version.

Also, autoNumeric had an issue when `'0'` got formatted to `'0.00'` in some cases. This has been fixed [here](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/issues/319), [here](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/issues/339) and in other commits. Could you please try the latest version in the `next` branch?